# What is the class/set which integral the operator map algebraic function to

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Integral is an operator, and it map a function to other one, $\int f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)dx_1dx_2\dots dx_n=F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$.

Now if $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)dx_1dx_2\dots dx_n$ is defined over $\mathbb{C}$ and  is algebraic function,then,what class is $F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what domain of integration you're choosing? The answer to that question affects the solution to your question a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "what class" - are you asking whether every entire algebraic function has an algebraic antiderivative, or something else?